# ember-data initialization error: "Uncaught TypeError"

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have just downloaded ember-1.0.0-pre.4.js and ember-data-latest.js and get the following error upon the initialization of the app:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object Ember.Application has no method 'registerInjection'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately *ember-data-latest.js* on GitHub isn't up-to-date with Ember Pre 4. You'll have to `git clone` the Ember DS repository, and then build them using `rake`.

You can find it [here](http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-data-latest.js) or the minified version from [here](http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-data-latest.min.js)

Comment: Helped me too, thanks ! Hey, we don't all use rake and rails, guys.

Comment: Those pastebins don't seem to exist anymore. You can get the latest versions here:
http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-data-latest.js
http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-data-latest.min.js

Comment: It's very ugly :( Why I need git and rake for get one js file... Ember is clever, but changes and releases... poof..

Answer (score 2):

you can get it from [http://cdnjs.com/](http://cdnjs.com)  concretely:

- //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember-data.js/0.8.0-latest20121123/ember-data-latest.min.js
- //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember-data.js/0.8.0-latest20121123/ember-data-latest.js