# ember-data.js failure on script init

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using all of the latest dependencies for emberjs and yet I end up with an error on initializing the scripts in the page at **ember-data-latest.min.js** with:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {...} has no method 'registerInjection'
```

Before even writing a single line for my app. Why is that?

Appreciate any kind help.

Here's my script list:

- jquery-1.10.2.min.js
- handlebars-v1.3.0.js
- ember-1.5.1.js
- ember-states.js
- ember-data-latest.min.js

And here's the full error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
    if (!wasApplied) {
      Class.proto(); // prepare prototype...
    }
    o_defineProperty(this, GUID_KEY, nullDescriptor);
    o_defineProperty(this, '__nextSuper', undefinedDescriptor);
    var m = meta(this), proto = m.proto;
    m.proto = this;
    if (initMixins) {
      // capture locally so we can clear the closed over variable
      var mixins = initMixins;
      initMixins = null;
      this.reopen.apply(this, mixins);
    }
    if (initProperties) {
      // capture locally so we can clear the closed over variable
      var props = initProperties;
      initProperties = null;

      var concatenatedProperties = this.concatenatedProperties;

      for (var i = 0, l = props.length; i < l; i++) {
        var properties = props[i];

        Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports mixing in other definitions, use createWithMixins instead.", !(properties instanceof Ember.Mixin));

        if (typeof properties !== 'object' && properties !== undefined) {
          throw new Ember.Error("Ember.Object.create only accepts objects.");
        }

        if (!properties) { continue; }

        var keyNames = Ember.keys(properties);

        for (var j = 0, ll = keyNames.length; j < ll; j++) {
          var keyName = keyNames[j];
          if (!properties.hasOwnProperty(keyName)) { continue; }

          var value = properties[keyName],
              IS_BINDING = Ember.IS_BINDING;

          if (IS_BINDING.test(keyName)) {
            var bindings = m.bindings;
            if (!bindings) {
              bindings = m.bindings = {};
            } else if (!m.hasOwnProperty('bindings')) {
              bindings = m.bindings = o_create(m.bindings);
            }
            bindings[keyName] = value;
          }

          var desc = m.descs[keyName];

          Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining computed properties. Define computed properties using extend() or reopen() before calling create().", !(value instanceof Ember.ComputedProperty));
          Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super.", !(typeof value === 'function' && value.toString().indexOf('._super') !== -1));
          Ember.assert("`actions` must be provided at extend time, not at create " +
                       "time, when Ember.ActionHandler is used (i.e. views, " +
                       "controllers & routes).", !((keyName === 'actions') && Ember.ActionHandler.detect(this)));

          if (concatenatedProperties && indexOf(concatenatedProperties, keyName) >= 0) {
            var baseValue = this[keyName];

            if (baseValue) {
              if ('function' === typeof baseValue.concat) {
                value = baseValue.concat(value);
              } else {
                value = Ember.makeArray(baseValue).concat(value);
              }
            } else {
              value = Ember.makeArray(value);
            }
          }

          if (desc) {
            desc.set(this, keyName, value);
          } else {
            if (typeof this.setUnknownProperty === 'function' && !(keyName in this)) {
              this.setUnknownProperty(keyName, value);
            } else if (MANDATORY_SETTER) {
              Ember.defineProperty(this, keyName, null, value); // setup mandatory setter
            } else {
              this[keyName] = value;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    finishPartial(this, m);
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    m.proto = proto;
    finishChains(this);
    sendEvent(this, "init");
  } has no method 'registerInjection'
```

Comment: I created a jsbin with those libraries and it seems to work: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mahufige/1/edit

Comment: Where did you get `ember-data-latest.min.js` from? Is your issue a similar one to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600080/ember-data-initialization-error-uncaught-typeerror

Comment: 10x it worked out. It seems that the source I got from github isn't the latest indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to use the latest version which gets published at [Ember build site](http://emberjs.com/builds/).

The latest build for Ember Data is [found here](http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember-data.min.js).